# Assign to Pandas dataframe in place with method chaining

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use assign() to create new columns by method chaining (which is an elegant way of expressing a number of operations on a dataframe), however I can’t seem to find a way to do this without creating a copy which is much slower than doing it in place, due to the associated memory allocation. It it possible to do this in place with a simple method that modifies in-place and returns the resulting dataframe?

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2), columns=['a', 'b'])

df['c']=df.a+df.b # in place, fast, but cannot chain
df.sum() # ….takes two lines of code

df.assign(c=df.a+df.b).sum() # compact but MUCH slower as assign() returns a copy of the df rather than assigning in place
```

Answer (score 3):

`.assign` can take a callable that will accept the current state of the dataframe within a chain.

```py
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2), columns=['a', 'b'])
      .assign(c=lambda df: df["a"] + df["b"])
      .sum()
)
```

Comment: Yes, but does that not still not involve returning a copy? It is much slower than the two line in-place example…

Comment: @ScarletPumpernickel you can't method chain and operate in-place. in-place ops return `None` and break the chain

Comment: can you see a conceptual reason why implementing assign(… , inplace=True) would not be desirable, at least as syntactic sugar to facilitate elegant and compact syntax? Am I missing something? For one thing, .loc[] does not make a copy…

Comment: @ScarletPumpernickel the point of `assign` is to be used in a chain. Since `inplace=True` would inherently break that chain, using e.g., `df[new_col] = new_values` suffices

Comment: Why would assign(inplace=True) break the chain any more than day groupby() or loc[], which do not copy the whole dataframe and can be chained effectively?

Comment: Both `groupby` _and_ `loc` make complete copies of the DataFrame in most circumstances.

Comment: "*can you see a conceptual reason why implementing assign(… , inplace=True) would not be desirable?*" That's generally avoided due to the [command-query separation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation).

Comment: @ScarletPumpernickel inplace assigns would break the change because inplace operations return `None` and so the next method in the chain would not be available

Comment: So currently I am assigning the df to a variable, adding a column in-place, passing that variable with the new column to a plotting function, then deleting the variable to not pollute the namespace (working in Jupyter). This would be much cleaner if the in-place methods would just return ‘self’ to allow chaining, rather than returning nothing. I fail to see the reason why there is opposition to this syntax.

Comment: if it's returning `self`, then it's not operating in place. if you don't like that, take it up with the pandas developers, not people trying to give you free help on stackoverflow

Comment: Understood, and your help is certainly very much appreciated. Thought I must have been missing something but doesn’t seem like it, will take it up with pandas folks.