# pandas chaining and the use of "inplace" parameter

Tags: python, pandas, method-chaining, in-place

For pandas DataFrames in python, multiple member methods have an `inplace` parameter which purportedly allow you to NOT create a copy of the object, but rather to directly modify the original object*.

[**Edited to add:* however, this proves to not be the case [as pointed out by @juanpa.arrivillaga](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529#issuecomment-323890422). `inplace=True` DOES copy data and merely updates a pointer associated with the modified object, so has few advantages over a manual re-assignment to the name of the original object.]

Examples that I have seen online for the use of `inplace=True` do not include examples where chaining is used. This comment in a related SO thread may be an answer to why I don't see such examples anywhere:

> [you can't method chain and operate in-place. in-place ops return None and break the chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69591787/assign-to-pandas-dataframe-in-place-with-method-chaining#comment123007080_69591820)

But, would "inplace chaining" work if you put an `inplace=True` in the last entry in the chain? [*Edited to add:* no] Or would that be equivalent to trying to change a copy created in an earlier link in the chain, which, as it is no longer your original object, is "lost" after the chain statement is complete? [*Edited to add:* yes; see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76466765/4228193)]

The use of large data objects would seem to preclude the notion of chaining without the ability to do so in-place, at least insofar as desire to maintain a low memory overhead and high computational speed. Is there an alternate implementation of pandas or, e.g. an equivalent of R's data.table available in python that might be appropriate for my needs?  Or are my only options to not chain (and compute quickly) or to chain but make redundant copies of the data, at least transiently?

Comment: If the second-to-last entry in chain returns a copy and the last entry modifies it inplace but doesn't return it, it is lost.

Comment: " Or would that be equivalent to trying to change a copy created in an earlier link in the chain, which, as it is no longer your original object, is "lost" after the chain statement is complete?" yes, yes that is what would happen. Did you try it?

Comment: Also note, `inplace` does not generally help you actually conserve memory. See [this claim by a core contributor](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529#issuecomment-323890422). The keyword argument is being deprecated in Pandas v2 (instead, there will be new [COW improvements](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#copy-on-write-improvements))

Comment: Frankly, it seems rather strange to me to abandon the whole pandas project because you cannot use method chaining. which is essentially syntactic sugar.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga your mention that inplace does not actually do what the name suggests (changing an object without copying or pointer magic), led me down a welcome rabbit hole. As there don't appear to be any advantages to using inplace and limited advantages of chaining, I may go back to "plain vanilla" pandas.  I hope that, down the road, someone does develop an intuitive, fast library for big data in python.  I will edit my post with a note about inplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'value' : [2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, np.NaN]})

df.sort_values('value').drop_duplicates().dropna(inplace=True)
```

Expect:

```
   value
2    1.0
0    2.0
4    3.0
5    4.0
6    5.0
```

Result:

```
   value
0    2.0
1    2.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    3.0
5    4.0
6    5.0
7    NaN
```

Answer: No, `inplace=True` at the end of the chain does not modify the original dataframe.

Comment: It's more relevant that `drop_duplicates` does *not* use `inplace=True` than it is that `dropna` does. `df.dropna` is simply never called, which is why `df` is not modified.

Comment: @chepner sorry, I don't understand, why is `dropna` never called?

Comment: `dropna` is called, but *not* on `df`; it's called on whatever is returned by `df.sort_values('value').drop_duplicates`. (I'm distinguishing between the bound method and the unbound method.)

Comment: To be clearer, chaining is just a way to avoid a temporary variable. The chained  form is equivalent to `t1 = df.sort_values('values'); t2 = t1.drop_duplicates(); t2.dropna(inplace=True)`, except no reference to `t2` is retained in the chained version.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want it, you can create a wrapper like so (untested):

```
class Wrap():
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
    
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        m = getattr(self.df, name)
        def f(*args, **kwargs):
            m(*args, **kwargs, inplace=True)
            return self
        
        return f

# Usage:

Wrap(df).func1(*params1).func2(*params2)
```

Comment: Dataframes are _certainly_ mode complex objects than this naive wrapper can comply with. It does not forward any operator like `__getitem__` for example.

Comment: @jsbueno It was only meant to show basically how this could be done if one really really wants it.

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank you for the wrapper suggestion. I assumed there was a way but didn't know how off the top of my head. I appreciate that you took the time to explain this method. However, implementing this strategy is beyond the scope of what I currently wish to do.